# A fill in the blank question about "as ... as"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, as

Choose the best answer that.

> He is a very hardworking student. He studies English .... Arabic.
>
> 1. as soon as
> 2. as long as
> 3. as well as
> 4. as well

The book which the test comes from said that the answer is 1 and as soon as means "in addition to". I didn't hear this meaning before and I think this answer is not correct. So what is the answer? What does each one mean? I know that 4 is definitely out.

Comment: It's a bit contrived, but in certain contexts, ***as soon as*** could be used here (with the sense that he is ***as willing / keen*** to study English as he is to study Arabic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number 3 "as well as" is the correct answer.  "As well as" means "and also/additionally".  I suspect it's a misprint that the book says the correct answer is number 1.

Examples:

> I eat meat **as well as** vegetables.
>
> I fix foreign **as well as** domestic cars.
>
> I write fiction **as well as** non-fiction books.

"As soon as" = "immediately after".

> We will leave for the party **as soon as** you get dressed.

"As long as" = "while/provided something is true"

> **As long as** you get good grades, you can stay up late.

"As well" = "also"

> For the picnic, I brought cheese, bread, chicken, and potato salad, and a bottle of wine **as well**.